# FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres". Unable to connectt

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, authentication, pgadmin-4

I finally was successful in installing Postgresql in Ubuntu and it works almost perfectly in terminal. I wanted to also have a GUI of the same so i went ahead and installed pgAdmin4. When i try to create a server fro it, i get the error of failed password authentication. I have tried many solutions among them from this website https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/240751/error-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host-postgresql-pg-hba-conf-is-empty. I tried to locate the pg_hba.conf so i could change the password authentication from md5 to trust or peer, sadly the pg_hba.conf is empty. I'm using postgresql12 and pgAdmin4. From the photo is the error i got. I will appreciate any help

Comment: If `pg_hba.conf` were empty, you wouldn't be able to connect from `psql`. Please investigate some more. Typically, it are trivial mistakes that are hardest to find.

Comment: I opened it through Visual Code and it was empty, no text at all and it was read only. Or i should have opened it via another text editor?

Comment: PostgreSQL won't start with an empty pg_hba.conf.  The one you are looking at must not be the "real" one. If you can connect with psql, then you ask where the correct pg_hba.conf is by doing `show hba_file;` It doesn't matter what text editor you use, as long as you use it correctly.